# How to cascade drop down within a WebGrid in asp.net MVC Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am facing issue with cascading dropdown list inside a webgrid.
Here is the scenario.
i have two drop down lists, one for table name and one for column names. My cascading has to work in such a way that the after table is selected the columns related to that table should only reflect in the next drop down. Also then i choose a tableName based on some primaryKey , Foreign Key relation the columns should be selected from a method which creates an object of entity data model in a method which inturn returns a Json Object containing the column names
I intend to do it with a JQuery in my view but as i'm new to coding i'm stuck Frown | :( ... can someone please advice on what is going wrong with my code.

My View is as Follow

```
<div id="grid">
    @wg.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "gridTable",
    headerStyle: "gridHead",
            rowStyle: "gridRow",
    footerStyle: "gridFooter",
            alternatingRowStyle: "gridAltRow",
    columns: wg.Columns(
                         wg.Column("DestnColumn", "Destination Column"),
                                 wg.Column(header: "SourceTable", format: @item => Html.DropDownList("value", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceColumnModel[0].SourceTables)),
                                 wg.Column(header: "ColumnNames",format: @item => Html.DropDownList("value",new SelectList(string.Empty,"input_field_id","input_field_name"),"Select Column")),        // wg.Column(header: "SourceColumn", format: @item1 =>     Html.DropDownList("value1",      (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.SourceColumnModel[0].SourceColumnsNames)),
                                         wg.Column("DataSize", "Size"),
                                 wg.Column("DataType", "Data Type"))

)
    )
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function SelectInput(inputtype) {
    var filenamediv = document.getElementById('FileNames');
    var databasenamediv = document.getElementById('DatabaseNames');

    if (inputtype == 1) {
        databasenamediv.style.display = 'none';
        filenamediv.style.display = 'inline';
        $()
        @*@Html.Partial("_FileView")*@
    }
    else if (inputtype == 2) {
        databasenamediv.style.display = 'inline';
        filenamediv.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

my controller is as follow:

```
    public JsonResult GetColumn(string TableName)
{
List<string> ColName = new List<string>();
 int id = (from m in db.inputs where m.input_name == TableName select m).Max(p => p.input_id);
input_field Ifield = new input_field();
var str = (from m in db.input_field where m.input_id == id select new { m.input_field_name, m.input_field_id }).ToList();


return Json(new SelectList(str, "input_field_id", "input_field_name"));
}
```